# how to pass value from href to iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe

i am using anchor tag to redirect next page(demo2.aspx) from demo1.aspx. i wanted when i click a tag then it would be redirect to next page with value and set it to iframe.i dont want hardcode value in iframe.pls let me soluction

**demo1.aspx**

```
//here how to pass value"add.swf.html" with demo2.aspx
    <a href="demo2.aspx" >Add</a>
```

**Demo2.aspx**

```
<iframe src="add.swf.html" style="width: 1346px;height: 693px;">

</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below

```
<a href="demo2.aspx?value=add.swf.html" >Add</a> " >Add</a>
```

in demo2.aspx

```
<%

string value= Request.QueryString["value"];

%>

<iframe src="<%=value%>" style="width: 1346px;height: 693px;">

</iframe>
```

Comment: belwo code i am getting invalid expression
<%= 
 string value1= Request.QueryString["value1"];
  
  %>

Comment: pls remove "=" after <%, accidentally i wrote that. Answer has been edited.